How do I add a number (or index value) to the middle of a filename stored in a variable in BASH?
I have 15 text files that I regularly edit on a daily basis and I would like to compare the contents of all of these files with their backup copies using the UNIX diff command but in a simple bash shell script (instead of individually on the command line one by one) on a Terminal on a MacOSX with the latest version of BASH installed.
So far, I have created this script:
#!/opt/local/bin/bash

FILE1_L="/Path/to/file/Test1.txt"
FILE1_R="/Path/to/file/Test1 copy.txt"
diff -y -W200 -s --supp "$FILE1_L" "$FILE1_R"

FILE2_L="/Path/to/file/Test2.txt"
FILE2_R="/Path/to/file/Test2 copy.txt"
diff -y -W200 -s --supp "$FILE2_L" "$FILE2_R"

# etc down to

FILE15_L="/Path/to/file/Test15.txt"
FILE15_R="/Path/to/file/Test15 copy.txt"
diff -y -W200 -s --supp "$FILE15_L" "$FILE15_R"

I would like to add a number/index using a simple for-loop to the middle of a filename contained in a variable, one for the left file and one for the right file, and have just one diff command executed each time the loop is cycled.  Here is the pseudo-code;
FILE1_L=same as above
FILE1_R=same as above

FILE2_L=same as above
FILE2_R=same as above

# etc down to 

FILE15_L=same as above
FILE15_R=same as above

for loop with i as the index
{
    FILE_L="FILE"+$i+"_L"
    FILE_R="FILE"+$i+"_R"
    diff -y -W200 -s --supp "$FILE_L" "$FILE_R" > diff_output.txt
    # and later on maybe ask if the user wants to view the differences or not, etc
}

Question: Using BASH script, how do I add the value of the index variable i to the middle of the contents of FILE_L and FILE_R as shown in pseudo-code above?  So for example, if i=8, then FILE_L would be the string FILE8_L
I am not familiar with the detailed ins and outs of bash.

http://shellcheck.net is your friend, use it on all scripts until you do become familiar with the detailed ins and outs of bash so it will at least warn you about several of the more common, basic problems.

Also note ALLCAPS variable names are generally reserved for bash system and environment variables. lowercase is your friend :)

A couple of untested approaches (out of many possible solutions!):
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob

for file_l in '/Path/to/file/Test'+([0-9]).txt; do
    file_r="${file_l%%.txt} copy.txt"
    diff -y -W200 -s --supp "$file_l" "$file_r"
done

That just finds the left files, creates a file name from that for the right file, then diffs them.
If you really want to use specific suffix numbers though then you could alternatively do:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

base='/Path/to/file/Test'

for sfx in {1..15}; do
    file_l="${base}${sfx}.txt"
    file_r="${base}${sfx} copy.txt"
    diff -y -W200 -s --supp "$file_l" "$file_r"
done

Don't use all upper case for non-exported variables by the say, see Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization.

Thanks for the quick response.  Would this work if each pair of files was in a different directory and each file had a different file name? In my sample code, I just used “Test1.txt” and “Test1 copy.txt”, etc for simplicity, but in reality, each pair of files is in a different location on the drive.  Your second script is almost the answer I was looking for :-)  If I want to read up on this topic involving ${} what does it come under?  Thanks.

No. It's important when asking questions to provide truly realistic sample input and expected output so accept an answer to this question you asked then ask a new question with a more realistic [mcve]. ${file_l%%.txt} is parameter expansion, see https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion, and {1..15} is brace expansion, see https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion.

@TheEngineer In Bash and sh ${} is a way to refer to a variable name.  These are equivalent: echo ${some_var} and $some_var.  The difference lies in being able to apply parameter expansions within the braces {}, which can do things like search-and-replace, grabbing the first 4 characters of the string, removing trailing whitespace, or counting the number of characters in the string.

Comparing two files with different prefixes/suffixes, and a counter in the middle:
for Count in {1..15}; do

    File_Original="/some/source/folder/source_file_${Count}_suffix.txt"
    File_Backup="/some/backup/path/my_file_${Count}_ending.txt"

    # Compare the two files, store the output in a variable for later use
    Diff_Output="$(diff -y -W200 -s --supp "$File_Original" "$File_Backup" 2>&1)"

done

Explanation:
The code {1..15} is special Bash syntax telling it to expand this into a list of all the numbers from 1 to 15, giving you this line:
for Count in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15; do 

If you need zero padding on the numbers, you can use {01..15} which will expand to:
for Count in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15; do 

In a for loop like this, Bash simply iterates over each of the strings after the in keyword.  Strings are broken up by spaces, so use quotes if your strings contain spaces, like this:
for Fruit in "Red Apples" Pears Oranges "Green Apples" Mangos; do 

Bash also supports C-style for loops for more complex operations, but using the {1..15} style loop works fine.
For the File_Original="/some/source/folder/source_file_${Count}_suffix.txt" part, put whatever text you want before and after the ${Count}, which is the variable that counts up from the for loop.  You requested $i as your counter, and can use that instead of $Count, but I highly recommend using variable names that clearly define their purpose rather than just picking random alphabet letters.
I refer to the variable as ${Count} instead of $Count because otherwise it would think the text after it was also part of the variable name, e.g. $Count_suffix in this case.  The braces {} ensure Bash knows where the variable name ends.
The ${foo} syntax can also be used for special variable expansions, such as searching and replacing within the variable text.
Diff_Output="$(diff -y -W200 -s --supp "$File_Original" "$File_Backup" 2>&1)"

In this part $() is a Bash feature that runs a command in a sub-shell.  Whatever is within the parenthesis () is the command line to run.  The $() will expand to the output of the command, like $() was just another variable.
For example:
echo "My username is $(whoami)."

The only other oddity is the 2>&1 at the end of the command.  In a Bash shell there is standard output (stdout), and standard error (stderr) outputs.  Commands normally print regular messages on stdout, and error messages on stderr.
The $() expansion will not capture stderr, only stdout.  So the 2>&1 is required to ensure error messages are also captured, otherwise they would be sent to the screen, and not saved into the $Diff_Output variable.  2> redirects stderr, and in this case it is sent to &1 which is stdout (&2 is stderr).
Example of redirecting stdout and stderr to different files:
some_command 1>"Output.txt" 2>"Errors.txt"

Using foo > bar is the same as doing foo 1> bar.
Finally, be aware that the $Diff_Output variable will be overwritten each time the for loop iterates to the next number.  You could opt to store the 15 outputs into an array rather than a normal variable, like this:
Diff_Output[$Count]="$(diff -y -W200 -s --supp "$File_Original" "$File_Backup" 2>&1)"

And then you would access it later using something like this:
# Access directly
echo "${Diff_Output[5]}"

# Or using a counter
echo "${Diff_Output[$Count]}"

Hopefully this helps you on your Bash adventure!

Also note in bash, printf -v varname "format_str" "value(s)" can be used to produce fixed width numbers with leading zeros, e.g. for i in {1..10}; do printf -v num "%04d", "$i"; echo "$num"; done will fill num with 0001, 0002, etc.. on each iteration. Just another way to skin the formatting cat. (if you wanted to add text to your loop counter in a variable) - not needed in the way you have done it.
